# Android read text file from server

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked to death but I am not winning, I am trying to read a textfile from the server into a string, it was working partially few moments ago but the last paragraph was showing symbols only. I then specified my charset to "UTF-8" hoping it will solve my problems but now the entire text file is showing symbols. Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://lehakoeevents.co.za/dijo/weekly_content/stories/sway_rustenburg_22_08_15.txt");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

String story = bo.toString();
Log.i("", "New Response : " + story);
```

I tried adding the following to my connection request:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

But still showing symbols all over the place, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                    "http://lehakoeevents.co.za/dijo/weekly_content/stories/sway_rustenburg_22_08_15.txt");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
            InputStream is = buf.getContent();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");
            }
            Log.i("HI", "" + total.toString());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: dude, thank you so much. I was really hoping to use the HttpURLConnection class because the most of those classes have been deprecated, I am not complaining though, it worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You can use the last 8 lines of above code with HttpurlConnection too.